# implements chain not followed by compiler

Tags: typescript, interface, compiler-errors

I have this in code:

```html
interface OneThing {
}

interface AnotherThing extends OneThing {
}

interface ThirdThing extends AnotherThing {
}

interface ThingKeeper {
  getThings<T extends OneThing>(): T[];
}

class Thingamajigger implements ThingKeeper {
  getThings(): ThirdThing[] {
    return new Array<ThirdThing>();
  }
}
```

Typescript compiler give me an error on getThings() in Thingamajigger.

file: 'Sandbox.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Class 'Thingamajigger' incorrectly implements interface 'ThingKeeper'.
  Types of property 'getThings' are incompatible.
    Type '() => ThirdThing[]' is not assignable to type '() => T[]'.
      Type 'ThirdThing[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        Type 'ThirdThing' is not assignable to type 'T'.'
at: '14,7'
source: 'ts'
code: '2420'

Shouldn't this work?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message reported by the type checker, it is pretty obvious what's going on:

- `() => ThirdThing[]` is not assignable to `<T extends OneThing>() => T[]`
- `ThirdThing[]` is not assignable to `T[]`
- `ThirdThing` is not assignable to `T`

The type `ThirdThing` and `T` are not related, for example if you consider such a hierarchy:

```
   OneThing
  /       \ 
 T       ThirdThing
```

Therefore, the compiler says that it cannot be assigned for sure. The solution would be to to relate `T` and `ThirdThing` via the `ThingKeeper` class:

```
interface OneThing {
}

interface AnotherThing extends OneThing {
}

interface ThirdThing extends AnotherThing {
}

interface ThingKeeper<T extends OneThing> {
  getThings(): T[];
}

class Thingamajigger implements ThingKeeper<ThirdThing> {
  getThings(): ThirdThing[] {
    return new Array<ThirdThing>();
  }
}
```